# What does Desktop View / View Desktop Site actually do?

Tags: css, html, mobile, media-queries

Does anyone know how selecting the Desktop View option in a mobile browser affects CSS media queries and Javascript?

I'm making a site which is meant to be for mobile users only. When I select "Desktop View" when using the stock Android browser, it breaks the site. I want to effectively ignore the desktop view setting.

Thanks

Comment: I believe this option only change the user-agent.

Comment: Thanks Kraz, I do believe you're right - please could you offer this as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this option only change the user-agent.

Answer (score 4):

The 'Desktop View' in the stock android browser simply changes the user-agent (UA) string sent to the server. Without the option selected a typical UA string would look similar to the following:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android *{OS Version}*; en-gb; *{Device Model Information}*) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

With the 'Desktop View' option enabled this changes to something similar to:

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/11.0.696.34 Safari/534.24

As you can see the first example explicitly includes the word Mobile, it also informs us that it is an Android operating system. The second example mimics the user-agent string of a 'full-browser' critically by omitting the word Mobile.

More importantly, to specifically answer the original question in two parts;

**How does this option affect CSS media queries?**

It doesn't. CSS media queries themselves are unaffected by the UA string sent to the server. Typically when we talk about media queries we're making reference to the screen size / resolution / orientation of the device, all of which are unaffected by the 'Desktop View' option. The CSS behavior of the site would only be altered if the server were to provide a different response based on the UA string provided.

**How does this option affect javascript?**

This affects javascript if you (or a third party library you use) make use of the [Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) object to modify behavior based on the browser version.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't necessarily change the user agent, however it will set a session variable for the website for that user, so if they make a request it will skip the user agent check and simply return the desktop website.

[Example Code](http://tuts.pinehead.tv/2011/04/08/creating-a-show-desktop-website-button-for-your-mobile-site/):

```
<?php
//See if the browser is a mobile browser
// If it's mobile browser see if the user prefers desktop version
// IF the user does not the foward to mobile website.

$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/iPhone/i',$browser)) { $iphone = "true"; }
if(preg_match('/Android/i',$browser)) { $android = "true"; }


if($iphone == true || $android == true) {

    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['version'] != "desktop") {

        header("location: http://tuts.pinehead.tv/jqmobile/mobile.php");

    }


}
```

Comment: I was meaning when you select "View Desktop site" from the Android browser menu. I think user Kraz was correct in this case - it was all explained by the difference in the value of navigator.userAgent. I don't think it necessarily involves anything server side, or session variables. But your solution would be appropriate in some cases